# Are there any central trackers for COVID-19 trials?

Tags: medications, covid-19, vaccination

There are several aggregate central trackers for the spread of COVID-19. [Like this one, for example.](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/)

Is there anything similar for trials? Or trials in the pipeline? Either vaccines or treatments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking about trials

See the [clinical trials database](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=covid-19&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist=)

Answer (score 3):

Such a tracker is available on the [Milken Institute website](https://milkeninstitute.org/covid-19-tracker). It currently lists 52 vaccine candidates and 79 treatment candidates.

Update: one month later (May 4th) it lists 123 vaccine candidates and 199 potential treatments. Incredible!

Update #2: there are now 202 vaccine candidates and 316 potential treatments, as of August 8th

Comment: +1 for the updates. And the new awesome good news.

Answer (score 3):

As far as treatments are concerned, there is https://www.covid-trials.org/. It allows you to filter results by trial status (completed, recruiting, etc.), treatment and location. It also has links to trial results (where available) and registry information.

It does not have information on vaccine candidates, though.

**Reference:**

Thorlund A, Dron L, Park J, et al. A real-time dashboard of clinical trials for COVID-19. The Lancet Digital Health [Internet]. 2020 Apr 24 [cited 2020 Aug 9];2(6):E286–E287. Available from: https://www.thelancet.com/journals/landig/article/PIIS2589-7500(20)30086-8/fulltext

Answer (score 0):

One more tracker for COVID-19 trials: https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/trials-vaccines-by-country/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210226194811/https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/trials-vaccines-by-country/)).

[image]